# iPhone SE2: Strange box with percentage appears when pressing Home button

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone SE2 (2020). When I press the home button, a strange box showing "47%" appears. When I click an app icon, it disappears. The box always shows 47%. To the best of my knowledge, no assistive features are enabled.

How do I get rid of this?[image]

Comment: Have you restarted the phone? Have you forced the phone to restart?

Comment: Yes, restarted and force restart.

Comment: Have you restored the phone from backup?

Comment: No, I'm not sure if I have a backup.

Comment: If you have a backup, restore from backup to preserve whatever content is in the backup. If you don't have a backup, then I think all you can do is "restore iPhone," which will wipe all your content and settings. Beyond that...sounds like a trip to Apple Service.

Comment: Turns out that something more was reset when I accidentally let it run completely out of power. When I had charged it back to life, the box was gone and my device seems fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off and force restart didn't help, but letting the device drain the battery completely did help. After a complete drain and recharge, the box was gone.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for reporting back as an Answer; Comments aren't indexed, so this way the solution will be findable if someone searches.